# Does Active Assignment (Pardot) affect existing prospects?

Tags: pardot

Does Assigning prospects via salesforce.com Active Assignment Rule in Pardot affect prospects already in the database or would affect only new created ones?

Comment: Assuming by prospect you mean leads and by assignment rules you mean standard Salesforce assignment rules, the answer is only new leads. If there are any features in pardot that perform similar functionality I don't have an answer for you (which is why this is a comment).

Comment: Thank you gNerd. Yes i meant leads. I set pardot automation rule to "Assign prospects via salesforce.com Active Assignment Rule". You are right only new created ones are affected by the rule, the old leads are not reassigned. I made the rule live, but it is not working. I made sure pardot has the same queues as Salesforce, but still Leads are not going to the correct queue.